# Debug app version (built from Android Studio) has significantly lower performance then expected

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When I build debug version from "run app" button on a certain devices (Pixel 7) they runs significantly slower than it was some time ago (app hit 80-90 CPU on most of actions). There are no changes in configuration/gradle and etc. and release version works well as it should. I also noticed that if I run it via "profile app with low overhead"  button it also works as expected. This started to happen some time ago only for this certain device. What should I do to make it works in debug mode as it should?

I tried:

- Restarted device
- Deleted app via ADB
- Revoked dev mode and enabled it again
- Reistalled android studio and reset all settings
- Pulled project again (clean)
- Built from old commits
- Built by different gradle versions
- Built from other PC
- Build from other OS
- Changed package name
- Changed signing config

Comment: Could be an effect of InstantRun. I would try what happens if you build and install the APK by executing in the terminal `./gradlew installDebug` (build plain/solid APK and install it).

Comment: ./gradlew installDebug has not helped, "build APK" option also works very slow

Comment: @FlexeiPrata I have the same issue, very frustrated and I did't know (Run it via "profile app with low overhead" button it also works as expected) would back to normal. Thank you!

Comment: @FlexeiPrata I updated the android studio today with "Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2" and I don't have the slow issue anymore.